# for security purpose i want to encode source code of my html page

Tags: html

i want to design my html page such that; if some body wants to copy my source code from browser it should appear as in encoded format.
Is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. This said: Short answer is - why bother. If you put it on the web, it will be available to look at.

Comment: @mplungjan  thank you .... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of people who are afraid of copyright infringement, but as [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) said

> If you put it on the web, it will be available to look at.

And that, unfortunately for you, is the case for every site from Google to Stack Overflow.

If there are any *bad* cases of your site being plagiarized you should think of suing.

Comment: thanks for your valuable words.